# How to average a list based on criteria from a different list

Tags: excel

I have a workbook with many different sheets each of which links to a summary page. Column A on the summary page is a list of buildings in my company's portfolio. Columns B through F are various bits of information about those buildings - number of units, when they started sales, average price per square foot, etc. All of the following columns are months of the year - Jan, Feb, Mar, etc, and the rows are populated with monthly sales data at each of those buildings.

Each of the sheets consists of sales data at each of those buildings over a given month. The list of buildings on each sheet matches the list of buildings on the summary page exactly. However, those data sheets do not have the building data (PPSF, number of units, etc.) that the summary sheet has.

Here's what I want to do: on the summary sheet, I want to be able to average sales data from the data sheets using criteria that exist only on the Summary sheet. For example, the sheet labeled "March" has sales data for each building in the company's portfolio for March - no problem averaging that information.

But how do I average sales at buildings larger than 100 units?

Keep in mind that unit count information exists only on the summary page.

Is there a way I can do this without coding each individual month tab with this building-specific information?

Comment: Look into `AverageIf` and `AverageIfs`

Comment: I'm aware of these functions of course, but it's more complicated than that because this problem entails averaging one list of data using criteria from a different range. In other words, I have two different arrays - one with the list of buildings and their specs, the other with the list of buildings (which actually changes slightly month to month) and their sales data. I feel I would have to do some sort of AverageIfs array formula but I haven't been able to crack it yet.

Comment: Then  you will need to create a single table the correlates all the information then you can use the averageifs

Comment: Thanks. That's basically what I've resorted to at this point, but I was hoping to get around having to do that. I don't want to have to amalgamate everything into a single sheet. The monthly data sheets come from a download I do each month, and I would prefer to just be able to drop the data sheet into the workbook and have the summary page calculate averages based on criteria that exist only on the summary page. Ideally, I would avoid having to code the data sheets subsequently with PPSF, etc. information.

Comment: Without seeing the data and summary page it is hard for us to give concrete solutions.  There may be a way, It is hard to visualize with words only.

Comment: Damn...not sure how to upload an image of my table here...

Comment: You will need to save it to imugr or some other site and post a link in your Original Post.

Answer (score 0):

Use the AVERAGEIFS function. It works similarly to SUMIFS / COUNTIFS, if you are familiar with those. In short, it looks at a given row/column of data, then looks at a series of subsequent rows/columns of the same length, and averages only the items where those subsequent rows/columns match your criteria. For example:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(A:A,B:B, ">5",C:C,"<>"&$E$1,D:D, $E$2)
```

What this says is: For all cells in column A where:

-Column B of that row is larger than 5;

-Column C of that row does NOT equal whatever's in cell E1; and

-Column D of that row DOES equal whatever's in cell E2,

Take the arithmetic mean.

Adjust to suit your purposes by referencing the other sheets, as required.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of averageifs, which would be easy if the building-specific information was on each of the data sheets. But the problem is that information is not on the data sheets, it's only on the summary sheet. So the problem is I have two different arrays with just one range in common. I want to average a range in one of those arrays using criteria from a different array. Is this possible?

Comment: @AstralMilkweed see Scott's additional comment to your question - create a combined table which pulls in all data based on a unique ID key [set it up so that, say, column A contains each buildings asset #, and then columns B-> onward pull in data for that asset # from either table, as needed. This creates a single table, easy to work with]. Or if both tables are the same size, order them alphanumerically and just copy and paste onto a single sheet.